# google cardboard application in ios without using unity

Tags: ios8, xcode6, google-cardboard

I'm trying to make a spherical 360 video in my ios app with the Google Cardboard SDK.I have seen that all tutorials and samples talking about unity. I am not familiar with unity or GL.Is there any way to do this  without using unity ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's now an official SDK for iOS that doesn't require Unity.
https://developers.google.com/cardboard/ios/

Also for a simple 360 video player, check out VR View:
https://developers.google.com/cardboard/vrview

Answer (score 0):

You can try [EleVR](http://elevr.com/) the web player seems to run great on an iPhone (tested on iOS 9.1)