# Google Cardboard on iOS without using Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

It seems that all iOS applications using a google cardboard are based on Unity.
Is it possible to develop such an application without Unity?

Comment: Maybe this [SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161714)will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, however you would have to write your own engine. Unity is simply a game engine, so to do it without Unity (or any other game engine) means that you must gather the sensor data yourself and feed it into your own custom OpenGL engine for displaying your content. I am not familiar with iOS, but you may need to make your own Kalman filters for your sensor fusion. So, to make the app without any game engine is not an easy and quick task.

Developers usually use game engines because they spend less time troubleshooting bugs and more time developing the logic and other parts of the game, which require less skill, time, and knowledge than making a game engine.

Answer (score 0):

just released yesterday 
Google Cardboard SDK for iOS

https://developers.google.com/cardboard/ios/